# How to import csv file in PHP?

Tags: php, csv

I am very new to web development. In fact, I am just starting to learn.

Can somebody please give a complete but very simple example on how to import CSV file in PHP? I tried the one I got from the internet but I'm very confused because it's complicated for me. I am using the WAMP server with PHP 5.3.5, Apache 2.2.17, and MySQL 5.5.8. Please help.

I tried to paste the code but it's messy. Honestly, I am also very new to StackOverflow.

Comment: Can you amend your question to include as much of the error as you're comfortable with? It is much easier to troubleshoot that way.

Comment: Post the errors you're getting and the code you're using.

Comment: OK I'll rephrase it and include the code.

Comment: See example on the doc page for [fgetcsv()](http://php.net/fgetcsv). Hope that helps.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

From the PHP [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php):

```
<?php
$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        echo "<p> $num fields in line $row: <br /></p>\n";
        $row++;
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you! Very simple to use! How do I ammend this to save the items in the csv into an array?

Answer (score 20):

I know that this has been asked more than three years ago.
But the answer accepted is not extremely useful.

The following code is more useful.

```
<?php
$File = 'loginevents.csv';

$arrResult  = array();
$handle     = fopen($File, "r");
if(empty($handle) === false) {
    while(($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE){
        $arrResult[] = $data;
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
print_r($arrResult);
?>
```

Comment: In what way is it not useful? Seems to me like it works.

Comment: I meant that a working example as provided is always more useful than just a point in the right direction. If available of course and correctly written.

Answer (score 15):

The simplest way I know ( [str_getcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php#114764) ), it will import a CSV file into an array.

```
$csv = array_map('str_getcsv', file('data.csv'));
```

Comment: As noted in the linked comment, "that does not produce the desired results, if fields contain linebreaks."

Answer (score 6):

PHP > 5.3 use [fgetcsv()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) or [str_getcsv()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php). Couldn't be simpler.

Comment: Could be waaaaaaaaaay easier. Why not a function that takes a CSV string/filename and returns an array or exception? Jeepers why do i have to loop and parse. What is this, the 90s

Comment: @Jonathan Streaming is far more efficient than loading an entire 40GB CSV file into memory before operating on it.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the version to extract the specific columns by name (modified from [@coreyward](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5813196/55075)):

```
$row = 0;
$headers = [];
$filepath = "input.csv";
if (($handle = fopen($filepath, "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        if (++$row == 1) {
          $headers = array_flip($data); // Get the column names from the header.
          continue;
        } else {
          $col1 = $data[$headers['Col1Name']]; // Read row by the column name.
          $col2 = $data[$headers['Col2Name']];
          print "Row $row: $col1, $col2\n";
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use composer, you can try [CsvFileLoader](https://github.com/luchaninov/csv-file-loader)

Answer (score 1):

```
$row = 1;
    $arrResult  = array();
    if (($handle = fopen("ifsc_code.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
            $num = count($data);
            DB::table('banks')->insert(
                array('bank_name' => $data[1], 'ifsc' => $data[2], 'micr' => $data[3], 'branch_name' => $data[4],'address' => $data[5], 'contact' => $data[6], 'city' => $data[7],'district' => $data[8],'state' => $data[9])
            );
        }
        fclose($handle);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   $filename=mktime().'_'.$_FILES['import']['name'];

      $path='common/csv/'.$filename;

    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['import']['tmp_name'],$path))
{

if(mysql_query("load data local infile '".$path."' INTO TABLE tbl_customer FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' enclosed by '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES (`location`, `maildropdate`,`contact_number`,`first_name`,`mname`,`lastname`,`suffix`,`address`,`city`,`state`,`zip`)"))

    {
      echo "imported successfully";

}

echo "<br>"."Uploaded Successfully".$path;

}
```

look [here](http://tinyurl.com/b9yhv5y) for futher info