# Generate html code from csv file

Tags: php, html, csv, generated-code

I have one csv file separated by the following character |. The file has three columns; one is the url(COL1), the other is a small text(COL3), and the last one its an image location(COL2). I need a script that gives me the html code like this with the data from the csv file:

```
<a href="COL1"><IMG SRC="COL2" />COL3</a>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: which serverside language do you have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You using a serverside language, I'm assuming?  With php, you'd be after [fgetcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php).
Here's one example:  [How to import csv file in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5813168/how-to-import-csv-file-in-php)


**UPDATED:**

Try this:

```
$separation_char = "|"; // character separating fields
$filename = "test.csv";

$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen($filename, "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, $separation_char)) !== FALSE) {
        echo '<a href="' . $data[0] . '"><IMG SRC="' . $data[1] . '" />' . $data[2] . '</a>';
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```