# Unzip file with PHP

Tags: php, gzip

I have a gzip file. Into this file I have many csv files. I want to read only one of these files that are contained into the gzip folder. The name of the gzip folder that I want to read is 'com.instore'. And the name of the csv file  is 'second'.

I use the gzopen() to read the gzip folder. But now I don't know how to read the csv file contained inside.

1. So, how can I do this?
2. Do I have to close with the gzclose()?
3. The gzip is into a server directory. How can I reach it?

Comment: gzip files only store one file; rather, it's the compressed format of any file.

Comment: I assume you actually have a `.tar.gz` file.  http://stackoverflow.com/q/4878792

Comment: `tar -xzf myarc.tgz com.instore/second.csv`

Answer (score 0):

When you gzopen you dont uncompress it. you just creates a file pointer to it.

```
<?php
// get contents of a gz-file into a string
$filename = "/usr/local/something.txt.gz";
$zd = gzopen($filename, "r");
$contents = gzread($zd, 10000);
gzclose($zd);
?>
```

while $contents is your csv file as a string.

more info @ http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gzread.php

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the gzip file using this:
[How can I extract or uncompress gzip file using php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11265914/how-can-i-extract-or-uncompress-gzip-file-using-php)
and than using this:
[How to import csv file in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5813168/how-to-import-csv-file-in-php)
populate the database.