# Error when loading csv file in mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql, csv, fopen

Could some one help me out for some reason im getting an error and can not figure out why!!!!
I have about 45 columns and im only needing to use 1,2,3,4,7,8 from the table so i cant load everything.

```
    <? 
        $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","*******","*****","******");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
        //get the csv file
    $file = "tickets/feed/rtc.csv";
    $handle = fopen($file,"r");
    $count=0;
    $sid="32837459823";
    //loop through the csv file and insert into database
    do {
        if ($data[0]) {
            mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO carlist (id, stknum, vin, vt, stat, other, store_id) VALUES
                (
                    '".$count++."',
                    '".addslashes($data[7])."',
                    '".addslashes($data[8])."',
                    '".addslashes($data[2].$data[3].$data[4])."',
                    '".addslashes($data[1])."',
                    '".addslashes("0")."',
                    '".addslashes($sid)."'
                )
            ");
        }
    } while ($data = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",","'"));
    //
        ?>
```

Here is the errors im getting

> Notice: Undefined variable: data in
>   /home1/inventory/mobile/actions/loadsubmit.php
>   on line 139
>
> Notice: Undefined offset: 7 in
>   /home1/inventory/mobile/actions/loadsubmit.php
>   on line 139
>
> Notice: Undefined offset: 8 in
>   /home1/inventory/mobile/actions/loadsubmit.php
>   on line 140
>
> Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in
>   /home1/inventory/mobile/actions/loadsubmit.php
>   on line 141
>
> Notice: Undefined offset: 3 in
>   /home1/inventory/mobile/actions/loadsubmit.php
>   on line 141
>
> Notice: Undefined offset: 4 in
>   /home1/inventory/mobile/actions/loadsubmit.php
>   on line 141
>
> Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in
>   /home1/inventory/mobile/actions/loadsubmit.php
>   on line 142

Comment: Please look at this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5813168/how-to-import-csv-file-in-php

Answer (score 1):

Looks like $data is not defined until you hit

```
while ($data = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",","'"));
```

so when you're trying to access $data before that line you're getting an error because the variable doesn't exist.

Comment: Im editing this code from a website and learning as i go...I probably dont need this code then?....for what im doing

Comment: Just make it a while loop instead of a do-while loop. Put the condition at the top of the loop, that will probably help.