# "Column count doesn't match value count at row 1" error shows up when I try to upload more than 1 row. (CSV-file to MySQL-database)

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I got a very annoying problem at the moment. I try to create a CSV upload that writes to a MySQL database. The system works, but only when i got 1 row. When I got more rows, the error "Column count doesn't match value count at row 1" shows up.

Here's my php code:

```
DEFINE('DB_HOST', 'localhost');     // Server naam
DEFINE('DB_USERNAME', 'root');      // Gebruikersnaam
DEFINE('DB_PASSWORD', 'root');      // Wachtwoord
DEFINE('DB_DATABASE', 'wp3');   // Database naam

// Initialisatie
$databasetable = "users";
$fieldseparator = ",";
$lineseparator  = "\n";
$csvfile        = "backups/compleet.csv";
$output         = "";

// Database connection
$con = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);
mysqli_set_charset($con, "utf8");

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    die('Service kan niet geladen worden.');
}

// Perform checks with CSV file
if(!file_exists($csvfile))
{
    echo "File not found. Make sure you specified the correct path.\n";
    exit;
}

$file = fopen($csvfile, "r");

if(!$file)
{
    echo "Error opening data file.\n";
    exit;
}

$size = filesize($csvfile);

if(!$size)
{
    echo "File is empty.\n";
    exit;
}

// Get content from CSV file
$csvcontent = fread($file, $size);
fclose($file);

// Initialize CSV file variables
$lines      = 0;
$queries    = "";
$linearray  = array();

// Read each line from CSV file, clean data and put data in database
foreach(explode($lineseparator, $csvcontent) as $line)
{
    $lines++;
    $line      = trim($line, " \t");    
    $line      = str_replace("\r", "", $line);
    $line      = str_replace("'", "\'", $line);
    $linearray = explode($fieldseparator, $line);
    $linemysql = implode("','", $linearray);

    $query     = "INSERT INTO $databasetable VALUES('', '$linemysql')";

    // $queries .= $query . "\n";

    if (!mysqli_query($con, $query))
    {
        echo 'Fout: ' . $sql . '<br>' . mysqli_error($con);
    }
}

// Read all the rows from the table and print to screen
$sql            = "SELECT * FROM $databasetable";
$result         = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
$columns_total  = mysqli_num_fields($result);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    for ($i=0; $i<$columns_total; $i++)
    {
        $output .= $row["$i"] . ', ';
    }

    $output .= '<br>';
}

echo "<p>Er zijn $lines regels aan de tabel toegevoegd.</p>";
echo "<p>De database bevat nu de volgende data:<br>$output</p>";
```

And here is my csv file:

`id,username,password,firstname,lastname,permissions,image,thumb,header
 3,Frank,password,Frank,VanDeursen,author,frankImg.jpg,frankImg.jpg,tropical.jpg
 4,Kevin,password,Kef,Borgh,author,kev.jpg,kev.jpg,ocean.jpg`

Thank for the help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to import csv file in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5813168/how-to-import-csv-file-in-php)

Comment: Do you also get the error when you remove the leading double single quotes in VALUES in this line? `$query     = "INSERT INTO $databasetable VALUES('', '$linemysql')";`

Answer (score 0):

```
David, password, david, backname, author, stock.jpg, image.jpg, stock.jpg
Frank, password, frank, backname, admin, stock,jpg, image,jpg, stock,jpg
```

Your csv file has more columns in the second row check carefully `stock,jpg, image,jpg, stock,jpg` all having comma's instead of dots!

Comment: Sorry, that was just a wrong-example. It isn't the error i'm searching for. I have changed it. Thanks for your comment.